# How to configure logger level for ngx-logger in global config file

Tags: angular

I have recently included `ngx-logger` for my project for implementing a logger level within the application. I have hard-coded the logger level in `app.module.ts` within the configuration of `ngx-logger` but I need to implement this in some global config file.

I had followed a tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@ahmedhamedTN/enable-disable-angular-logging-based-on-production-environment-using-ngxlogger-dee531fb8374), which told me to hard-code the level within the configuration. The problem with this approach is that apart from the configurations already stated,if there is any other `environment` defined other than what I have coded it would produce an error. I want to remove this hard-coded configuration and instead use some "config" file for managing the environment variables. But I am not sure how to do that and there are no online resources which I could find.

here is my configuration:

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    AppAsideModule,
    AppBreadcrumbModule.forRoot(),
    AppFooterModule,
    AppHeaderModule,
    AppSidebarModule,
    PerfectScrollbarModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    //  Logger config based on environment
    LoggerModule.forRoot({
      level: !environment.production ? NgxLoggerLevel.LOG : NgxLoggerLevel.OFF,
      // serverLogLevel
      serverLogLevel: NgxLoggerLevel.OFF

    })
  ]
```

environment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  isDebugMode: true,
  lang: 'en',
  api: {
          grant_type: 'password',
          clientId: 'sugar',
          clientSecret: '',
          host: "https://blablabla.com:44375/rest/v11_1/",
          platform: 'custom_api',
        },
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**my goal**: finding a better logger level implementation instead of hard-coding

Comment: Why are you saying hardcoding? it is being changed according to dev or prod version.

Comment: The reason I said hardcoding was because there may be custom environments added that have different requirements. i am only considering the production environment in my configuration. If I want to add (say a mock) environment and it needs to have the same logging as production I would have to change this configuration again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1:

You can set another variable isdebug for all files.

For production
——————
isdebug=1

For debug
——————
isdebug=2

For mock
——————
isdebug=3

Your coding.
(environment.isdebug === 1 || environment.isdebug === 2) ? NgxLoggerLevel.LOG :: NgxLoggerLevel.OFF

## Solution 2:

If you want to change on the fly use env.js for configuration, The following solution is good

https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that I took a few days ago, facing the same task:

In app-module.ts:

```js
import { LoggerModule, NgxLoggerLevel, NGXLogger, LoggerConfig } from 'ngx-logger';

//...
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
   // ...
 ],
 imports: [
   LoggerModule,
   // ...
 ],
 providers: [   
   {
     provide: LoggerConfig, useFactory: () => Utility.loadJson<LoggerConfig>('/assets/loggerConfig.json', //
       { // defaults, in case file is not found:
         level: NgxLoggerLevel.WARN,
         // serverLoggingUrl: '/api/logs',
         // serverLogLevel: NgxLoggerLevel.OFF,
         // disableConsoleLogging" : true
       })
   },
   NGXLogger,
   //...
 ]
```

Then have your utility-method ready:

```js
export class Utility {

  static loadJson<T>(file: string, defaultObject: T, onError = (event) => null ): T {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', file, false);
    request.onerror = onError;
    if (request.overrideMimeType) {
      request.overrideMimeType('application/json');
    }
    request.send();
    if (request.status === 200) {
        return <T>JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    }
    return defaultObject;
  }
  // ...
```

Then create your loggerConfig.json file in src/assets:

```js
{
 "// levels:": "TRACE=0, DEBUG=1, INFO=2, LOG=3, WARN=4, ERROR=5, FATAL=6, OFF=7",  
 "level": 1, 
 "// serverLogLevel" : 5, 
 "// serverLoggingUrl": "/api/logs", 
 "// disableConsoleLogging" : true 
}
```

Now add `loggerConfig.json` to your `gitignore`-file and push the changes: You don't want developers overriding each other's settings.

The idea is, that usually the provided default is used, but you have the possibility to have your own override in a configuration file.