# ngx-logger implementation in angular

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I am new to angular and I am trying to add loggers to my angular 8 application. I have been following following tutorial
https://medium.com/@ahmedhamedTN/enable-disable-angular-logging-based-on-production-environment-using-ngxlogger-dee531fb8374
and able to understand most of the part. But  I have doubt regarding enable ngx-logger for different environment. I have two environment in my application i.e development and production. Found following solution on stackoverflow to resolve this::

[How to configure logger level for ngx-logger in global config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54668780/how-to-configure-logger-level-for-ngx-logger-in-global-config-file)

But problem with me is I am not able to understand solution 1 of accepted answer. Can anyone explain this solution

```
you can set another variable isdebug for all files.

For production —————— isdebug=1

For debug —————— isdebug=2

For mock —————— isdebug=3

Your coding. (environment.isdebug === 1 || environment.isdebug === 2) ? NgxLoggerLevel.LOG :: NgxLoggerLevel.OFF
```

where I need to set another variable isdebug for all files? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the default app setup you have the directory named `environments` with 2 files `environments.ts` and `environments.prod.ts`. 
First is the default, second will be substituted in place of default when you compile with --environment=prod. You can have any number of such files for different environments. You can define any variables there (or properties in environment const) as you wish.

So when you do `import { environment, .... } from '../environments.ts';` you will have the set of variables defined in file according to your environment. 
For example, define in dev:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  debugLevel: 1
};
```

and in prod:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  debugLevel: 3
};
```

import and use `environment.debugLevel` wherever you want

Comment: Thanks , I got it. Just one more question, while running how application will come to  know this variable  debugLevel value?

Comment: As I wrote in the answer - import it. `import { environment } from '../path/to/environments.ts';`

Comment: one more question I am following above link in my question to implement ngx-logger in my application. As per this link changes related to needed to be done on component side. Do I need to make some logging related changes in html pages of my application or method metioned in link will be suffficcient?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand you.

Comment: In any angular application we have two parts html and corresponding component. As per link I just need to implement ngx-logger in app.module.ts and use it in any component in my application. My question is do I need to make any change in html file to implement logger or method mentioned in link is sufficient?